# Why is my code for set_intersection slower than the std?

Tags: c++, optimization, std, set-intersection

I have the two functions below. I execute each one about 200K times, with random sorted vectors (each function gets the same two vectors, but the vectors change between runs). I'm a little confused because my code runs in about 500 ms total for all 200K iterations, whereas the STD function call runs in 440ms. Where is the ~60ms going? What is the STD doing (or not doing) that I've done differently?

I'm using Visual Studio 10 on core i5.

```
int getAndIntersectMine(std::vector<int>& resultContainer)
{
    std::vector<int> const& vector0 = getSomeVector();
    std::vector<int> const& vector1 = getAnotherVector();

    const int length0 = vector0.size();
    const int length1 = vector1.size();

    const int* ptr0 = &vector0[0];
    const int* ptr1 = &vector1[0];

    int i0 = 0;
    int i1 = 0;
    int numels = 0;

    while(i0 < length0 && i1 < length1)
    {
      if(ptr0[i0] == ptr1 [i1]) {
        resultContainer[numels++] = ptr0[i0];
        i0++;
        i1++;
      }
      else if (ptr0[i0] > ptr1[i1])
      {
        i1++;
      }
      else
      {
        i0++;
      }
    }

    return numels;
}


int getAndIntersectStds(std::vector<int>& resultContainer)
{
    std::vector<int> const& vector0 = getSomeVector();
    std::vector<int> const& vector1 = getAnotherVector();

    std::vector<int>::iterator last = 
      std::set_intersection(
        vector0.begin(),
        vector0.end(), 
        vector1.begin(), 
        vector1.end(), 
        resultContainer.begin());

    return last - resultContainer.begin();
}
```

Comment: how did you measure? 60ms isn't that much and might be measurement error as well

Comment: `getAndIntersectStds` also gets a `std::vector<int> const& resultContainer` parameter, right?

Comment: Since this is templated code, you can just look up the `std` version right?

Comment: Have you tried to switch `i++` to `++i`? Perhaps that might help..

Comment: stefan: I have two loops, each of which calls one of the functions the same number of times. I time each of the loops with QueryPerformanceCounter.

Shahbaz: Yeah, sorry. Edited the code to reflect it.

Comment: Maybe more a question for codereview?

Comment: Look at the assembly code.

Comment: This code won't compile `resultContainer` is not assignable.

Comment: @PeterWood: Sorry, fixed now. Copy-paste errors.

Comment: There is no difference between the generated assembly code on *Ubuntu clang 3.0-6*.

Comment: @PeterWood: then clang wins this one over MSVC 10 :-)

Comment: @PeterWood: There is when I compile with Visual Studio 10, under Release. I don't know assembly, but the two functions have differences. Thanks for checking, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is that you are using subscription instead of iterators.

while iterating std algorithm does(in pointer eqv.)

```
int * beg = &v[0];
int * end = &v[0] + v.size();
while(beg != end)
{
  ...
  ++beg;
}
```

your is more arithmeic-extensive

```
int * beg = &v[0];
int i = 0, s = v.size();
while(i != s)
{
  //use beg[i], which is *(beg + i)
  ...
  ++i;
}
```

And also post increment... but I think it is optimized

Comment: Is `<address> + 1` cheaper than `<address> + <offset>`?

Comment: @anjruu: you've accepted this answer. Does that mean you made the corresponding change, and that the performance difference disappeared when you did so?

Comment: @Nick I meant that he also increments counter on each iteration

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yes, I changed my code to increment the pointers rather than incrementing indices, and using the indices to de-reference the pointers, and I'm getting comparable performance as the std::set_intersection.

Comment: I looked at the generated assembly code and there is no difference on between OP's functions, for `Ubuntu clang 3.0-6`.

Comment: @kassak Ah yes I see what you mean.